# Open foo.r executable files in gedit

Tags: 12.10, unity, gedit

I'm editing a bunch of foo.r files (source R files for an R packages) in Ubuntu Unity 12.10.  Every time I click on one of these files to open it in gedit, a dialogue box comes up:  "Do you want to run foo.r, or display its contents?" and then I have to click on a "display" tab.  Can I make it open automatically in gedit?  Note that gedit is already set as the default open-with program.

Comment: This is just a link, but you can disable that dialogue from settings. I just found this: http://www.zartl.info/?p=17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation 'display'
```

Or you can launch `dconf-editor` and navigate to /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences, then select the `executable-text-activation` key. Here is its description:

> What to do with executable text files when they are activated (single
>   or double clicked). Possible values are "launch" to launch them as
>   programs, "ask" to ask what to do via a dialog, and "display" to
>   display them as text files.

Comment: This seemed to work!  Now I wonder what org.gnome.nautilus.preferences is -- does it exist somewhere as a text file that I could also have opened and edited manually?

Comment: "GNOME session daemon is responsible for setting the various parameters of a GNOME session and the applications that run under it." Settings are stored in .config/dconf/user, but it is not manually editable.

Comment: @zkurtz I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  However, when I type "dconf -editor" at the command line, I just get "error: unknown command -editor".  Is there another way to "launch"?

Comment: @zkurtz `dconf-editor`, no spaces.

Comment: @zkurtz I noticed you didn't mark as "accepted" none of the answers to your other [questions](http://askubuntu.com/users/115913/zkurtz?tab=questions). Just click the checkmark at left of an answer. I recommend you read the [about page](http://askubuntu.com/about), it's very informative.

Comment: Thanks, I click on the up arrow but had not noticed the checkmark.